# I want to be able to pull in the error log from BIOS across a network

Tags: c#, logging, wmi, bios

I want to be able to pull in the error log from BIOS across a network. Looking at Win32_BIOS in MSDN I did not see anything defining the error log. Would love to do this in C# with WMI, but am open to suggestions. Is it possible?

Win32_BIOS does not have a property (don't know if that is the right term) that contains the BIOS error log. Is there a library, API, etc. that I can use to pull this information locally or from the network?

Comment: It appears that no one has an answer for this. I assume it is only possible for specific motherboards and with their own API

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it is not possible to do this in such a way that will apply across a spectrum of motherboards as the requisite commands and interfaces will be hardware specific.

Some motherboards may contain an API call that will allow this, however, I have never come across one myself.